# Creating dictionary from strings containing a specific letter

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a text file that contains test results.

The text file looks like this:

```
NETAPP-MIB::enclTempSensorsCurrentTemp.1 = STRING: 29C (84F) ambient, 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 57C (134F), 37C (98F), 57C (134F), 44C (111F), 59C (138F), 40C (104F), 45C (113F), 58C (136F), 42C (107F)
```

My goal is to get all the results that contain a number with the letter C.
But I manage to get only the first value

For example this is what I get:

```
{'TEST sensor num 0': '29C'}
```

This is my code:

```
import re

def get_names(ip):
    """Get the server name according the IP address"""
    names = {"TEST": "10.205.110.226", "TEST2": "10.205.111.216"}
    if ip in names.values():
        for key, val in names.items():
            if ip == val:
                return key
    else:
        return f"No Recognized unit {ip}"


def get_temps_servers():
    """ Return A dict mapping from sensor name to sensor value """
    result = {}
    count = 0
    with open("test.txt", "r") as newdata:
        text = newdata.read()
    for ip in online_server:
        name = get_names(ip)
        for c in re.findall(r"^.*?(\d+C)", text, flags=re.M):
            result[f"{name} sensor num {count}"] = c
            count = count + 1
    print(result)
    return result


global online_netapp
online_server = ["10.205.110.226"]

get_temps_servers()
```

What I want to get is result like this example:

```
{'TEST sensor num 0': '29C', 'TEST sensor num 1': '36C', 'TEST sensor num 2': '36C'}
```

And will continue like this as long as there is a number with C.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The regex `r"^.*?(\d+C)"` can only match a string once, because `^` means the beginning of the string, and a string only has one beginning. Applying `.findall` doesn't help because there is only one possible match: the one that starts at the beginning of the string. `.*?` tries to match as few characters as possible before the `(\d+C)`, thanks to the `?`; but it still only matches one specific amount of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will nudge you in the right direction:

```
import json
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}C")
long_string = "NETAPP-MIB::enclTempSensorsCurrentTemp.1 = STRING: 29C (84F) ambient, 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F), 57C (134F), 37C (98F), 57C (134F), 44C (111F), 59C (138F), 40C (104F), 45C (113F), 58C (136F), 42C (107F)"
d = {
    f"TEST sensor num {index}": temp
    for index, temp in enumerate(re.findall(pattern, long_string))
}

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "TEST sensor num 0": "29C",
  "TEST sensor num 1": "36C",
  "TEST sensor num 2": "36C",
  "TEST sensor num 3": "36C",
  "TEST sensor num 4": "36C",
  "TEST sensor num 5": "36C",
  "TEST sensor num 6": "57C",
  "TEST sensor num 7": "37C",
  "TEST sensor num 8": "57C",
  "TEST sensor num 9": "44C",
  "TEST sensor num 10": "59C",
  "TEST sensor num 11": "40C",
  "TEST sensor num 12": "45C",
  "TEST sensor num 13": "58C",
  "TEST sensor num 14": "42C"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your regex is not correct, it only look for only upto first number (29c) match. Check it here https://regex101.com/r/sGVyac/1

Try excluding the caret like this `(\d+C)`, https://regex101.com/r/A40nuu/1

Answer (score 0):

this code will works:

```
from sys import stdin
inputString=stdin.readline().split()
outputDict=dict()
for i in range(len(inputString)//2):
    outputDict["test sensor num{}".format(i)] = inputString[2*i]

print(outputDict)
```

if input be : 29C (84F), 36C (96F), 36C (96F)

output will be :
{'test sensor num0': '29C', 'test sensor num1': '36C', 'test sensor num2': '36C'}